# Access to sendgrid.com was denied

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

When I tried to open sendgrid through heroku I get this error:

Access to sendgrid.com was deniedYou don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I get the same issue

Comment: It seems that account is not activated since I tried to login with valid credentials. I used this as a add on in heroku. As work around I created one from sendgrid website and activated right away. Now I can access the UI

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a recurring issue on SendGrid's side.

You can try to log in at https://app.sendgrid.com/login via the username and password set in the Heroku config. You probably get an authorizzation error saying to contact SendGrid support. Trying to re-create the addon from the CLI will show `User status - banned`.

You need to contact [support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us). You can only do that with a registered account though. At this point you might decide to look for a better service. :(

See also this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/298044/95552